# Javascript Fetch API not returning data

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fetch-api

I have made a Restful API using flask in Python that returns "Hello World".

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class MyApi(Resource):

    def get(self):
        return "Hello World"

api.add_resource(ProjectxApi, "/get/info")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

I'm trying to get the data from the API through the fetch method in JavaScript. The thing is that the data returned doesn't include "Hello world". I'm new to JavaScript (I code in Python), so excuse me if this is a basic question :)

JavaScript code

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get/info', {
mode: "no-cors"
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

[image: This is what is displayed on the console:]

Comment: what does the python console window show?

Comment: Character sequences `ProjectxApi` and `MyApi` feel somewhat dissimilar.

Comment: Please ignore that MyApi and ProjectxApi is the same, I'll edit it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch method will return a response object. You need to call the text method.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/get/info', {
mode: "no-cors"
}).then(async response => {
  const data = await response.text()
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Hey I tried this but I'm getting the following

Comment: Promise {<fulfilled>: ''}[[Prototype]]: Promisecatch: ƒ catch()constructor: ƒ Promise()finally: ƒ finally()then: ƒ then()Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"[[Prototype]]: Object[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: ""

Comment: You probably missed that await keyword.